# how to create scoped widgets in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can you create widgets from html scripts in your page? Let's say I have:

```
<script type="text/html" id="widget-simple">
    <div class="widget-simple">
       This is my widget and he's called {{ test }}
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="widget-complex">
    <div class="widget-complex">
       This is my complex widget and he's called {{ test }}
    </div>
</script>
```

And I want to create a widget with the following scope:

```
function createWidget(name, class) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.class = class;
}
var widgetList = [];
function createWidgetList() {
   for(var i=0; j=3; i<j; i++) {
       var class = i < 2 ? "simple" : "complex";
       widgetList.push(new createWidget("widget "+i, class));
   }
}
createWidgetList();
```

This will all be done in a controller hopefully, but I'm trying to skim as much JS down as possible to make sure it's obvious what I'm asking for. In essence I'll have an array of widgets, each having their own properties. I can modify these properties and the html will update itself, but only for that widget, not them all. So at the start I should have three widgets on my page called "test 1", "test 2" and "test 3", and because they're all divs with nothing else, it'll just be this text.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <div ng-repeat="w in widgetList">
           <!-- Somehow render the widget here -->
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, you may have noticed I have two different types of widget, which are defined in two script tags. I want, on creation, for the correct script tag to be used in getting the templated html. Once initially created, the widget class does NOT need to change the html.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into directives https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-first-directive

Comment: but how can you define which directive to use dynamically? or which object. I want to expand this into completely different widgets with different properties

Comment: A directive represents a new html element, the html attributes will define the interface for this new element. Like any html element you can make it look like what you want and reuse it where you want. Read the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out... sample http://jsfiddle.net/Lxs038m5/

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('one', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
        },
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><p>{{text}}</p><button ng-click="changeText()">test</button></div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.changeText = function (txt) {
                scope.index += 1;
                scope.text = scope.index;
            };
            scope.restore = function () {
                scope.text = "test",
                scope.id = 1,
                scope.index = 1
            };
            scope.restore();
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('two', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Directive two</div>'
    }
});

myApp.directive('dynamic', function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            attr.$observe('dynamic', function (val) {
                element.html('');
                var directives = $parse(val)(scope);
                angular.forEach(directives, function (directive) {
                    element.append($compile(directive)(scope));
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.directives = ['<one/>', '<two/>'];
    $scope.add = function (directive) {
        $scope.directives.push(directive);
    }
    $scope.modifyText = function () {

        var last = $scope.directives[$scope.directives.length - 1];
        console.log(last);
        last.changeText("tt");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div dynamic="{{directives}}" ng-model="text"></div>
    <button ng-click="add('<one/>')">Add One</button>
    <button ng-click="add('<two/>')">Add One</button>
    <button ng-click="modifyText()">change</button>
</div>
```